# VideoJs not playing on Browser and Devices

Tags: laravel, video.js

I wrote an app for Video Player using video.js, but its not playing when I clicked on play.

I tried to inspect on the browser and I saw this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)
>       at videojs (video.js:21689)

Then when I checked (video.js:21689) I have this:

> if (!tag || !tag.nodeName) {
>       // re: nodeName, could be a box div also
>       throw new TypeError('The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)'); // Returns
>     }

```
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.10.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

@if(strstr($media->mime_type, "video/"))
<div  oncontextmenu=”return false;”>
    <video controls controlsList="nodownload"  id="videoElementID" playsinline>
        <source   src="{{str_replace('http://localhost:8000','http://example.com/public',$media->getUrl())}}" type="video/mp4" >
    </video>


</div>




@elseif(strstr($media->mime_type, "audio/"))
 <div style="magin:0 auto;">
    <audio  controls controlsList="nodownload"  style="width:100%;">
        <source src="{{str_replace('http://localhost:8000','http://example.com/public',$media->getUrl())}}" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.10.2/video.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.sc.gl/videojs-hotkeys/0.2/videojs.hotkeys.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

const player = videojs('vid1', {});
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
            function takeTest() {
            $('.lectureArea').hide();
                    $('.testMarker').hide();
                    $('.testArea').show();
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#videoElementID').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
});
</script>
```

I expect the video to play when I clicked but not happen

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass video control id

```js
const player = videojs('videoElementID', {});
```

Comment: where do I put it

Comment: just replace vid1 with videoElementID in your script code

Comment: I did it, but still not playing

Comment: Best guess is that the extra complexity in your SOURCE element isn't working as you expect.